# I want to update the Server certificates on SharePoint Web Applications. How to do it?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, certificate, iis7

I want to update the Server certificates on SharePoint 2013 Web Applications. How to do it? Our Central Admin is now running on http instead of https, it is a major concern ?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint itself does not manage certificates in IIS.  It’s up to you to manually provision updated certificates for the related websites in IIS.